# Using NUnit, (how) can I test code that sets Thread.CurrentThread.Name?

Tags: nunit

### Consider this Test

```
[TestFixture]
class Sample
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Foo";
    }
}
```

**If I `debug` this test, it passes** without error.

**If I `run` this test, it fails** with the following exception

> System.InvalidOperationException : This property has already been set and cannot be modified.

*In run mode*, the test's thread's name is "NonParallelWorker".

*In debug mode*, the test's thread's name is `null`

As a constraint, assume the code-under-test is not allowed to change, and attempts to set the thread's name, without checking for null first.

E.g.

```
public void SampleMethodUnderTest()
{
     // It is important that this method gets to set this field.
     Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Important Value";
}
```

My search through [the documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Engine-Parallel-Test-Execution) and other's posts has come up dry...

### Question

**Is there any way to disable/modify NUnit's thread-naming behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `RequiresThreadAttribute`.

```
[TestFixture]
class Sample
{
    [Test, RequiresThread]
    public void Test()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Foo";
    }
}
```

I think this will work currently, although the fact that this creates an unnamed thread may be an implementation detail, and not something that will necessarily work reliably going forward, I'm not sure. The alternative of course is to create your own user-controlled thread in the test, and pass any exceptions back to NUnit.

Comment: It'll have to do for now. Thanks!